# HAproxy in neo4j configuration

Tags: neo4j, haproxy

Ref : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/high-availability/haproxy/

I try to configure HAProxy as said above. I try writing to master and read from slaves, as suggested. When the read is happening the salves is not up-to date with the master, resulting in discrepancy(after some time lag it is updated). How to ensure that data is in sync with master before reading?

Answer (score 0):

First thing make sure you have configured neo4j.conf correctly. ha.tx_push_factor determines to how many slaves a transaction should be pushed to synchronously. When setting this to ha.tx_push_factor=-1 you have immediate full consistency.

If inconsistent more, then read this [link](https://neo4j.com/blog/advanced-neo4j-fiftythree-reading-writing-scaling/) for consistency. There they are telling that, splitting should be based on consistency, not read vs write